# Suppress R Markdown Heading from TOC

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I have a bookdown project where I would like to exclude a heading from the table of contents. From [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1625#issuecomment-558854773) and the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/toc-unlisted.html), it appears this should be possible by adding the unlisted and unnumbered classes, e.g.,

```
# Section heading {.unlisted .unnumbered}
```

However, when I apply these classes, only the unnumbered seems to have an effect. That is, the section heading still appears in the TOC, but without a number (i.e., the same effect as `# Section heading {-}`).

A minimal example is in [this repo](https://github.com/wjakethompson/bd-reprex), and the rendered book [here](https://bd-reprex.netlify.app/). Am I missing something to make this work?

Session info:

```r
rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
#> [1] '2.9.2.1'

xfun::session_info()
#> R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
#> 
#> Locale: en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / C / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> Package version:
#>   base64enc_0.1.3 compiler_4.0.0  digest_0.6.25   evaluate_0.14  
#>   glue_1.4.1      graphics_4.0.0  grDevices_4.0.0 highr_0.8      
#>   htmltools_0.4.0 jsonlite_1.6.1  knitr_1.28      magrittr_1.5   
#>   markdown_1.1    methods_4.0.0   mime_0.9        Rcpp_1.0.4.6   
#>   rlang_0.4.6     rmarkdown_2.1.9 stats_4.0.0     stringi_1.4.6  
#>   stringr_1.4.0   tinytex_0.23    tools_4.0.0     utils_4.0.0    
#>   xfun_0.14       yaml_2.2.1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It looks like as in rmarkdown it works but not in bookdown. Perhaps submit a issue on github.

Comment: @J_F Thanks, I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/894). I tried using normal R Markdown with `rmarkdown::html_document()` output, but I'm getting the same results ([repo](https://github.com/wjakethompson/rmd-reprex) and [rendered document](https://wjakethompson.github.io/rmd-reprex/index.html)).